# Autocomplete with parameters in Autokey

Tags: autokey

I'm using autokey to improve my productivity, I create a sample script with abbreviation that trigger when the tab key is pressed, and the next code is executed by autokey:

```
output = "My phrase"
keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

And it work with simple phrases, but I need send parameters in the abbreviation and I need that Autokey use that parameters to generate the phrase. For example I need that with the abbreviation abb-param1-param2, Autokey output the phrase:

This is the message, and you send the parameters: parameter 1: param1, paremeter 2: param2.

My problem with this is  that I cant get the word before the cursor text to split it with the '-' separator and take the two last positions of the generated array like parameters to generate the new phrase.

Somebody know what can I to do to solve this problem ? 
Thank you.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: That two lines are my code, I am using autokey, but I have no idea how can I get the word before the cursor text when I press tab in the abbreviation.

Comment: Then you may like this : [Lintalist4Linux](https://sl5net.github.io/Lintalist4Linux/)